# Unknown receiver datePicker

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm following a tutorial from Lynda regarding creating a UIDatePicker, and here's what my code looks like:

ViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datePicker;

...

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"
...

@implementation ViewController

...

- (IBAction)displayDate:(id)sender {
    NSDate *chosen = [datePicker date];

    ...
}

@end
```

but for some reason XCode is giving me an error: 
"unknown receiver 'datePicker'

Just a note, the datePicker is linked. Is there something that I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Forget to `@syntesize`

Your `UIPickerView` to your **.m** file

and also  your can access by `UIPickerView` by name `_datePicker`

Comment: ah yes stupid mistake thanks. should be @synthesize datePicker;

Answer (score 1):

In this case you have `datePicker` *property* which is accessible by `self.datePicker`, or instance variable (generated for you by compiler) `_datePicker`. You really want the former.

Answer (score 0):

When using properties, you must call self first:

```
NSDate *chosen = [self.datePicker date];
```

Or

```
NSDate *chosen = [[self datePicker] date];
```